# how to write python wrapper of a java library

Tags: java, python, binding, word-wrap, cpython

How can we write a python (with CPython) binding to a Java library so that the developers that want to use this java library can use it by writing only python code, not worrying about any Java code?

Comment: First question, why aren't you using [Jython](http://jython.org/)?

Comment: Because of numpy as it not possible to work numpy with Jython. And the python developers nowadays prefer (and feel more comfy) to work with numpy. But thanks for your suggestion :-).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could try this way:

- Use **Jython** instead of CPython to write Python code http://www.jython.org.
- Integrate Jython code with Java code through **Apache Bean Scripting Framework** http://commons.apache.org/bsf/

If you definitely need to use CPython, then **Apache Trift** could be interesting for you: http://thrift.apache.org/ So you could make additional scalable abstraction layer and integrate your Java code with different languages (not only Python)

If you need a really low-level interface you could look at JNI http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jni/ for investigation. But I think it will take a lot of time to integrate your code with CPython using JNI.

Answer (score 2):

I've used JPype in a similar instance with decent results. The main task would be to write wrappers to translate your java api into a more pythonic api, since raw JPype usage is hardly any prettier than just writing java code.